# Understanding conditional operator

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=11,c=13;
    *((a)?&b:&c)=a?b:c;
    printf("%d %d %d ,"a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the output of `*((a)?&b:&c)=a?b:c;` statement

Comment: Do you have an understanding of the ternary `? :` operation in general? `x ? y : z` means *if `x` is true, then `y`, otherwise `z`*. Also note that a non-zero integer in C is "truthy" (evaluates as "true").

Comment: "If `a` is non-zero, dereference the address of `b` (or `c` if `a` is _not_ non-zero) and set it equal to ... if `a` is non-zero, `b`, otherwise, `c`"

Comment: FYI-That code won't compile.

Comment: Probably a typo; the comma in your `printf` string, should be behind the quote in order to have it compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it up into parts:

```
*((a)?&b:&c)  =  a?b:c;
```

We're assigning a value.  What's `a?b:c`?  Since `a` is true, `a?b:c` evaluates to `b`, i.e. `11`.

Now let's look at what we're assigning to:

```
(a)?&b:&c
```

Since `a` is true, this selects `&b`, the address of `b`.  So we have

```
*&b = b;
```

So we're simply assigning `b` to itself.

Answer (score 2):

Lets comprehend this monster:

`*((a)?&b:&c)=a?b:c;`

Take the first evaluated part:
`(a)?&b:&c`: simply means if `a` is not zero then get the address of `b`, otherwise get the address of `c`.

Second evaluated part:

`*(...)` dereferences an address to the actual value. In this case this evaluates to `*&b` which is just `b` (`*` is the inverse of `&`).

The right hand side `a?b:c` evaluates to `b` (as it does at the left hand side).

i.e. you just wrote down `b = b` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
*((a)?&b:&c)=a?b:c;
```

In this first `*((a)?&b:&c)`

if `a` in non-zero then `address of b` else `address of c`. As here `a` is `10` therefore result will be `address of b`.

Then it is dereferenced  that means value at that address means value of `b` i.e `11`.

Then this `a?b:c`  .Test - if `a` is `non-zero` then `b` else `c`. As `a` is `non-zero` therefore result is `b`.

And at last what we get is

```
   b=b;
```

Comment: Thanx to all of u for ur replies